# The environment variables obtained by splicing in linux are not parsed

Tags: linux, shell, ctf

As we all know, we can use $HOME to print the current directory just like:

`$ echo $HOME`

And it will print:
`/home/tsingshui`

But if I use:

`$ __="$""H""O""M""E";echo ${__}`

It just print:

`$HOME`

Is there any way to make it continue parsing out the current directory without using numbers or letters?

Comment: There are ways, for example `eval echo ${__}`  but it is not recommended to do such things.

Comment: Can a similar function be achieved without using letters or numbers?

Comment: Is this some kind of coding puzzle?